# What is the relation between honest verifier zero-knowledge and non-interactive zero-knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm not clear about the relation between the following definitions:

1. zero-knowledge protocols;
2. honest verifier zero-knowledge;
3. non-interactive zero-knowledge.

To my best understanding, *zero-knowledge protocol* commonly refers to "interactive" zero-knowledge protocol, and non-interactive zero-knowledge is not called a "protocol" because it is not interactive.

For honest verifier zero-knowledge, it is a property belonging to the zero-knowledge protocol, because in interactive zero-knowledge systems, the prover makes a proof relying on some messages sent from the verifier. Therefore, the honesty of the verifier should be considered.

However, in non-interactive zero-knowledge system, there is no interactive before the prover making a proof, so no honest verifier property should be considered.

I'm not sure the correctness of the above. Is there any mistake?